# Dynamic table name in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0

I am using Entity Framwork with a database-first approach. I want to change the table name or view name dynamically based on conditions.

Here, I am using `V_OVT_VLD_340B_DNA_CLD` or `V_OVT_B_table` or `V_OVT_c_table`  to get the records.

Based upon the source, I need to call the different table name and get the records. The whole code snippet is the same, except for the table name.

Please refer below code

```
private dOVT_OutlierViewEntities db = new dOVT_OutlierViewEntities();

if(source == "a")
{
    var result = this.db.V_OVT_VLD_340B_DNA_CLD.Where(x => x.DNA_PGM_PRTN_ID == partitionId && x.CLIENT_ID == clientId).ToList().Select(y => new ValidationModel
                {
                    claim_validation_test_id = new List<byte?> { y.CLAIM_VLD_TEST_ID },
                    claim_id = y.CLAIM_ID,
                    Provider_ID = y.Provider_ID,

                }).Take(id).ToList();
}

if(source == "b")
{
    var result = this.db.v_OVT_B_table.Where(x => x.DNA_PGM_PRTN_ID == partitionId && x.CLIENT_ID == clientId).ToList().Select(y => new ValidationModel
                    {
                        claim_validation_test_id = new List<byte?> { y.CLAIM_VLD_TEST_ID },
                        claim_id = y.CLAIM_ID,
                        Provider_ID = y.Provider_ID,

                    }).Take(id).ToList();
}

if(source == "c")
{
    var result = this.db.v_OVT_C_table.Where(x => x.DNA_PGM_PRTN_ID == partitionId && x.CLIENT_ID == clientId).ToList().Select(y => new ValidationModel
                    {
                        claim_validation_test_id = new List<byte?> { y.CLAIM_VLD_TEST_ID },
                        claim_id = y.CLAIM_ID,
                        Provider_ID = y.Provider_ID,

                    }).Take(id).ToList();

}
```

I want to modify the above implementation by dynamically attaching the table name to db context based upon condition.

```
string tableName = string.empty

if(source == "a") 
    tableName = "aTable";

if(source == "b")  
    tableName="bTable";

this.db.tableName.where().....
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can go with a switch condition to set the table type and use that with context

```
switch (tableName)
        {
            case "a":
                tableType = typeof(V_OVT_VLD_340B_DNA_CLD);
                break;
            case "b":
                tableType = typeof(v_OVT_B_table);
                break;
            default:
                tableType = typeof(v_OVT_C_table);
                break;
        }

var query = context.Set(tableType);
var result = query.Find(); //filter with this query condition
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do something like this..

```
   string tableName = string.empty

    if(source == "a") 
        tableName =db.GetTable("aTable");

    if(source == "b")  
        tableName=db.GetTable("bTable");


    and then query like..

     tableName.where()
```

Comment: What GetTable() method meant. i am not able to find any method named "GetTable" in context