# Accessing to a table by the string name LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I would like to access to a database table from an string identifier belonging to an equipement. I need to do it like this way because according to the equipement selected I will have an string with the table name with data to request. I test the access to my database and everything is ok.
How to resolve this issue please? Thanks in advance

Request:

```
var query = (from donnees in "String Name of my table"
             where donnees.Chrono >= dateDebut.Ticks
             select donnees).Any();
```

My database class:

```
public partial class PcVueContext : DbContext
    {
        public PcVueContext()
        {
        }

        public PcVueContext(DbContextOptions<PcVueContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<AICommonParameters> AICommonParameters { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<tab_LOG_TRACA> tab_LOG_TRACA { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<tab_UA_ACT> tab_UA_ACT { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<tab_UA_CUV> tab_UA_CUV { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<tab_UA_ECR> tab_UA_ECR { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<tab_UA_ENG> tab_UA_ENG { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<tab_UA_EVAA> tab_UA_EVAA { get; set; }
```

Comment: might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345855/dynamic-table-name-in-entity-framework

Comment: Sounds like a bad database design. But can you not just do `from donnees in (tableName == "tab_LOG_TRACA" ? tab_LOG_TRACA : (tableName == "tab_UA_ACT" ? tab_UA_ACT  : ...`?

Comment: What result type would you expect if your query accesses different tables? Types are very important in C# - think about types first.

Comment: @Charlieface Yes it's maybe the problem but i can't change the design because it cames from another application. I gonna try your solution i think is a good idea! i will let you know Thank u